# how to add code folding to output in visual studio output window

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, code-folding, output-window

It is possible to use code folding inside the source in visual studio, however it would also be very useful if folding could be added to output made to the visual studio output window

If you want to write to output window from within a unittest case then you can use following:

```
#include "CppUnitTest.h"
using namespace Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework;

TEST_METHOD(testingsomething)
{
    Logger::WriteMessage("Hello output window");
}
```

However if output is large, then it would be very useful to add some folding to it - is that possible in visual studio? I know it is possible in the VIM editor

Comment: I think it is not possible to fold. However the Output Messages are divided by categories, and you can pick the ones on the context menu checkboxes: https://i.imgur.com/AqmAiRv.png ; For outputting, you can use the `TRACE` macros or  `OutputDebugString`

Comment: if the output window could validate html, then that would also be a solution, but I do not think it is possible pt.